# PowerBI replace column names with values from a table containing translations

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop, powerbi-embedded

My report has visuals as tables, that display data. These visual names or value names are displayed in english. Once the data is published and then embedded, it needs to be displayed in the according language that is selected by a user.

How to change the value names, without messing up the data?

For example, here would be a visual:

|Electricity| 1 | 5 | 6 | 10 | in english

|Electricidad| 1 | 5 | 6 | 10 | in spanish

The dataset contains multiple tables from which data is taken and then visualized, but the translated values are in one table in one column. The table has a column `fieldname` that is like an identifier in all of the languages available, and `text value` that contains all of the translations. How could I make a measure or something, to dynamically replace the names but not touch the values?

The report has a table and a pie chart and maybe something can be done with the field `Value`, when selecting the pie chart. Any help is welcome, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was a little more complex, than anticipated. basically, the report was being embedded in a website and would display it with some additional features. it all went down to just being run through JS and filtered, which language to display. in PBI it displayed all of the languages and their fields - in the end, only 1 language stayed. resource not friendly, but got the job done.

Answer (score 1):

if your report is going to be embedded, you can leverage external tool like **Metadata Translator** to automatically translate the metadata (column names, measures, ...) to the language of your choice using the locale of the user opening the report.

You can fetch the tool from [this link](https://powerbi.tips/product/business-ops/). The tool is available in GitHub but you need to build it on your computer to install it, I found that installing it through Power BI Business Ops is much easier.

It's fairly simple to use and you can even automate the translation part trough API as Azure Cognitive Service or Google Translate. Behind the hood it's leveraging features that have been available in SSAS for a long time. You can even see the translation using another external tool like **Tabular Editor**, but it's harder to manage them from there.

Last but not least, Microsoft [released very recently a very good series of videos to achieve multi language report](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/building-multi-language-reports-for-power-bi-in-2023/). It's not so easy to set up but I would have been quite glad to have this kind of documentation when I had to figure this all by myself few years ago...

Hope this helps.